# SSRS Report Viewer 2012 Run Time IE11 issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the Report Viewer 2012 for the SSRS Reports and in the IE11 i am not able to get the fixed header while scrolling the report viewer. It is displaying as Scrolling for entire report viewer but not the table part.

How can i resolve that to fix the headers while scrolling the grid rows part only and not the entire report viewer.

Comment: you need fixed header for matrix/table in SSRS ????

Comment: http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/10/ssrs-repeat-tablix-header-on-page-scroll.html

Comment: already the fixed header is working in all browsers and even in ie8,9,10 also, but not working in IE11.

Comment: ok ,go to IE 11 Setting Icon >"Compatibility View Setting" and add you server name then refresh and check the report

Comment: It is working in Compatibility mode but we cannot tell to the end user to set the compatibility mode. Then how can we achieve this?

Comment: i added my server link into IE Setting>Internet Options>Security>Local Intranet>Sites>Check Automatically detect intranet network. and in advance add server link

Comment: Can i do this in the Server (IIS) so that the end users may not change the settings at their side?

Comment: Yes, You have to change on Server

Comment: I have changed under the server and unable to see the result